# How to Turn Off Automatic Termination of Suspended Apps

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm trying to debug my Windows Store App when it gets suspended (trying to prevent my server app from kicking my WSA client when it gets suspended and stops responding to keep-alive messages).  But Windows keeps terminating my app almost immediately after it suspends it.  Is there a way to prevent Windows from terminating suspended apps?  I've searched the interwebs and the group policy editor for such a setting, but the best I can find is a setting to prevent it from auto-terminating apps on shutdown, which doesn't help me.  And of course running in the debugger and pressing the Suspend button doesn't help either, since the app doesn't actually get suspended.  I guess I could hack in some debug code to make it pretend to be suspended, but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: The machine has 8GB already, which should be plenty considering my app uses 600MB and it's the only thing running beyond the normal services.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command line tool [PLMDebug](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj680085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is part of the [Debugging Tools for Windows package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#installation_directory), can be used to exempt an app from the Process Lifetime Management (PLM) policies.  When put into debug mode, an app will not be subject to termination and will not be automatically suspended.

Usage:

```
plmdebug /enableDebug <PackageFullName> [OptionalDebuggerCommandLine]
```

Once you've exempted it from PLM automatic suspension and termination, you can use `/suspend` to force a manual suspension.